# customize dictionary key and values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about change dictionary format.

The dictionary is :

```
{'index': 'cfs_nucleus_bespoke_88260', 'host': 'iaasn00018224.svr.us.jpmchase.net', 'source': '/logs/tomcat7inst0/localhost_tomcat7inst0_access_log2018-11-02.txt', '_time': '2018-11-02 19:46:50.000 EDT', 'count': '1'}
```

I want to ask is there a way for me to change the format like below:

```
{"column1":{'index': 'cfs_nucleus_', 'host': 'iaasn00018224.net'}, "column2":{'source': '/logs/tomcat7inst0/localhost_tomcat7inst0_access_log2018-11-02.txt'}, "column3":{'_time': '2018-11-02, 'count': '1'}}
```

Comment: There probably is a way. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
dict1 = {'index': 'cfs_nucleus_bespoke_88260', 'host': 'iaasn00018224.svr.us.jpmchase.net', 'source': '/logs/tomcat7inst0/localhost_tomcat7inst0_access_log2018-11-02.txt', '_time': '2018-11-02 19:46:50.000 EDT', 'count': '1'}
d1_items = list(dict1.items())
col_width = 2
dict2 = {f'column{col_num // col_width + 1}': {k: v for k, v in d1_items[col_num:col_num + col_width]} for col_num in range(0, len(dict1), col_width)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBRT8MgFIXf@yt465p1FFDnbOKb/gPfjCFI2Yqj0PTCnFn62yt0LvWN3POdw7m3//Gts3fT1GjpKXpGl1zbRp3zGuVyD9wGaVQA/qmgd0fFdzu2JXmJ8taBT5AWAiwhhO4Yu8dwGnAA/NV3shWgsFU@weDCIFXCK@MOUHnXSeEftQVP4kQKk@L4/zEXUioAHnkWwzeUbgjD/jznca@7OW6REH2q77f1A8GxDHp9eUucdMHOLWk@Zg3l2qsO4pJGg1/NG@N5tCqKTDrDv3Xj26izLIksnWMfQ0zo7CXpNnSoqtCCrhEdY/7lWKMT2rsBHcv40BbdPnv/s9U3@3pxf4yz5aZE1yDsQa1IiYyy135FufDFmPWDttfmrJimXw)

There are a few moving parts that interact to create this solution:

### [Dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Python has a neat trick where it allows you to embed `for in` loops in iterable and dict declarations to efficiently cycle and modify a set of elements. Here, the outer iterator is `range(0, len(dict1), col_width)`: this goes through a sequence of integers starting from 0, and progressively increases by `col_width` until it is greater than or equal to the size of the list, which functions to choose the start index of each `col_width`-sized dict segment.

### Tuple unpacking

`dict1.items()` is convenient because it returns a [dict view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dictionary-view-objects) of 2-tuples of each dictionary key and its value. Later, we utilize tuple unpacking `k: v for k, v in d1_items[ ... ]`, where a tuple of variables is flattened into two variables that can then easily form a key-value pair of the currrent dictionary comprehension. (This is only in newer versions of Python.)

### [List slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/8117067)

`d1_items[col_num:col_num + col_width]` is basically a way of getting a sublist. The syntax in relatively straightforward: starting from position `col_num`, get a sublist up to and excluding the element `col_num + col_width` (i.e. a sublist of size `col_width`).

### [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Preceding a string with `f` makes it a formatted string literal. Anything within `{` `}` is interpreted as literal Python syntax (with the exception of `'`, `{`, and `}`, which may vary behavior by context.) Here, in `f'column{col_num // col_width + 1}'`, it allows us to label each column with a bit of division and a +1 offset to start counting from 1 instead of 0. (This is new to Python 3.6)